# How can we improve our compilation flow with Specman?

Tags: specman

We are working on a large design, for which the verification environment is complex. It contains 5 internal VIPs ( 3 of them we own and debug, doing minor changes and tweaks), CDNS unipro VIP and a low level services package we uses for all of our environments.  Our e compilation flow is long and tedious, and for every change we make in our code base , our turnaround time for fixing is 10 mins.
How can we improve our compilation flow for increasing our team effectiveness?

Answer (score 0):

Work in compiled mode. 
Compile your code in parallel. 
Use specman advance option which let you save and restore, reseed and dynamic load.

Answer (score 0):

- use multiple cores for much faster compilation time (-mc switch to sn_compile.sh).  Requires advanced options license

Answer (score 0):

Compile your code in compiled mode using multi core compilation. It will reduce the compilation time significantly.
You can use this compilation also for debugging instead of the interpreted mode.
This capability is already included in the last hotfix of your installed release.

Answer (score 0):

Use SAO: use multi process compilation.
Download latest fix, as from version 13.1 you don't need a special verstion.
You can also use compiled code and compile only the modules you changed (multi stage compilation).

Starting version 14.1 you can compile the code to an elib file.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your code. You can also use parallel compilation. Another thing you can do is to use reseed and dynamic load

Answer (score 0):

In addition to multiple cores compilation, from 14.1 can use elibs to prevent recompilation of modules that were not changed.

Answer (score 0):

What we do for normal development is only compile the code that we will normally never change (base libraries, VIPs from other vendors, code reused from previous projects, etc.). Any code that we develop for that particular project is loaded interpreted on top. This gives a smaller turnaround time when we have to change something (because you just do a quick "reload").

For regression testing, we compile everything up to the testbench top and load the tests on top.